# Resources for socket programming

Tags: sockets

I am new comer to the world of socket programming.I have been wondering to find any good resources for socket programming.Any website or book...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two classic books will get you in a good shape for pretty much any network programming:

- [**TCP/IP Illustrated, Volume 1: The Protocols**](http://www.kohala.com/start/tcpipiv1.html), by W. Richard Stevens, gives solid understanding of how TCP/IP works.
- [**UNIX Network Programming**](http://www.unpbook.com), same author, teaches socket API from basic to advanced topics.

Answer (score 2):

Illustrated TCP/IP is something everyone doing actual socket programming should read:

http://portal.aauj.edu/portal_resources/downloads/networking/illustrated_tcpip.pdf

But I think you mean programming websockets from javascript? I doubt you need a book specifically about this topic. Read up on communicating with sockets in general. Learn the stuff outside the sandboxed javascript implementation.

If you're already up to snuff about networking communications, here's a websockets tutorial:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/start-using-html5-websockets-today/